# Syntax error when trying to define series of numeric variables in python

Tags: python, variables, syntax

I need to define a series of variables to be zero and then update them as the rest of my program counts instances of a bunch of different cases.

I don't know why I can't just set it up like I have below, but no matter where I put this structure, IDLE says there's a syntax error and highlights the first instance of `2bktools`.

```
import os
import csv

os.chdir('/Users/me/Desktop/SubjError')
for subject in ['100307', '100408', '101107', '101309', '101915']:

    2bktools = 0
    0bkbody = 0
    2bkfaces = 0
    0bktools = 0
    2bkbody = 0
    2bkplaces = 0
    0bkfaces = 0
    0bkplaces = 0
    #counts and updates instances of each variable
```

I think there must be a more effective way to set a series of variables to zero, but I don't know what it would be.

Comment: Variable names cannot start with numbers in Python.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote them and accept the best one. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus :)

Comment: Thanks to all for the help! I was googling everything I could think might generate this error, but not starting a variable with a number (however obvious it may be) did not occur to me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to define variables that start with numbers. You can't do that in python.

[Here is some info](https://realpython.com/python-variables/#variable-names) on precisely how variable names can be structured.

Answer (score 3):

Variable names cannot start with numbers in Python.

Anyway, for your use case, I think a nested `dict` would be useful:

```
from pprint import pprint

subjects = ['100307', '100408', '101107', '101309', '101915']
keys = ['2bktools', '0bkbody', '2bkfaces', '0bktools', '2bkbody', '2bkplaces', '0bkfaces', '0bkplaces']

data = {subject: {key: 0 for key in keys} for subject in subjects}

pprint(data)
```

Output:

```
{'100307': {'0bkbody': 0,
            '0bkfaces': 0,
            '0bkplaces': 0,
            '0bktools': 0,
            '2bkbody': 0,
            '2bkfaces': 0,
            '2bkplaces': 0,
            '2bktools': 0},
 '100408': {'0bkbody': 0,
            '0bkfaces': 0,
            '0bkplaces': 0,
            '0bktools': 0,
            '2bkbody': 0,
            '2bkfaces': 0,
            '2bkplaces': 0,
            '2bktools': 0},
... more of the same...
```

You can then access any attribute you want using the standard indexing syntax; for example, `data['100307']['2bktools']`.